# How can i add items to my generic custom list without using the .Add() method?

Tags: c#, list, generics, addition

My question is in the title.
How can I add items to my generic, custom list without using the .Add() method ?

```
public class MyArray<T>
{
    public List<T> _myArray;

    public MyArray()
    {
        _myArray = new List<T>();
    }

    public void Add(T obj)
    {
        //I wanna add item without using the .Add() method. 
    }
}
```

Comment: what's wrong with the `Add` method? is this some type of homework?

Comment: use [Insert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @Aomine yes -.-

Comment: If it's for a homework, I doubt you are supposed to be using `List<T>`? They probably want you to make your own implementation of an array that can grow (dynamic array), basically what `List<T>` does? See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can create an `index` variable internally:

```
class MyArray<T>
{
      public List<T> _myArray;
      private int index = 0;

      public MyArray()
      {
          _myArray = new List<T>();
      }

      public void Add(T obj)
      {
          _myArray[index++] = obj;             
      }
}
```

Note, that if/when you add a `Remove` method, you'll need to make sure the `index` value is modified to accommodate the change etc.

Comment: i will try. ty @Aomine